# Copy dynamic range until end of line in Word

Tags: regex, excel, vba, ms-word

*** I think I have solved my issue with .MoveEndUntil method and replacing all next lines in the word doc with "*" so that I can just change the range to the next symbol like this:

```
oRange.MoveEndUntil Cset:="*"
```

I am having trouble with my copying technique as I try and copy text from Word to Excel via the below VBA. Right now I have the code going through a file that you select, making some formatting changes to it (because I don't know how to dynamically copy it), searching the file for a string, hard coding the copy range, then pasting in Excel. What I'm trying to go through and iteratively search for in the document is the below information:

- Model: Cisco AIR-3802I-B-K9
- Antenna:Int, AIR-ANT2544V4M-R, AIR-ANT2524V4C-R=,etc.
- Power 2.4 GHz: 08dBm
- Power 5.0 GHz: 10dBm
- Mounting Height: 10ft/3.04m
- Clip type: Universal
- Building: Central
- Floor: 02
- Room #: C2-100
- Installation Instructions: Example installation instructions of varied length and will change for every unit

So what I would hopefully like to do is search for the key term before the colons and then only copy the range after the colon until end of the line. Such that when I search for "Building:" it will copy and paste "Central" from word into the specified Excel cell without all my hard coded Range moves. Because the length of text after the colons can vary depending on the information being submitted. If anyone could please provide any assistance or guidance it would be greatly appreciated. I know my code is dirty and unclean but right now it worked for what I needed it to do which is why I'm trying to now improve it.

```
Sub LocateSearchItem()
Dim shtSearchItem As Worksheet
Dim shtExtract As Worksheet
Dim oWord As Word.Application
Dim WordNotOpen As Boolean
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Dim FilePath As String
Dim oRange As Word.Range
Dim LastRow As Long ' last row with data in shtSearchItem
Dim CurrRowShtSearchItem As Long ' current row in shtSearchItem
Dim CurrRowShtExtract As Long ' current row in shtExtract
Dim myPara As Long


On Error Resume Next

Set oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err Then
    Set oWord = New Word.Application
    WordNotOpen = True
End If

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

oWord.Visible = True
oWord.Activate

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

With fd

    .Filters.Add "Word Files", "*.docx", 1
    .Title = "Choose a Word File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .Show = True Then

        FilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(FilePath)

With oDoc.Content.Find
        .Text = "Notes"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

With oDoc.Content.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

With oDoc.Content.Find
        .Text = "^l"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

oDoc.Save


Set shtSearchItem = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7)
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count < 2 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=shtSearchItem
End If
Set shtExtract = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5)

' AP name
For CurrRowShtSearchItem = 2 To 2
    Set oRange = oDoc.Range
    With oRange.Find
        .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1).Text
        .Font.Name = "Helvetica"
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        While .Execute = True
            oRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, 5

            CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1

            shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract + 1, 1) = oRange.Text

            oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        Wend
    End With
Next CurrRowShtSearchItem

CurrRowShtExtract = 0

'AP model
For CurrRowShtSearchItem = 3 To 3
    Set oRange = oDoc.Range
    With oRange.Find
        .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1).Text
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        While .Execute = True
            oRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, 6

            CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1

            shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract + 1, 20) = oRange.Text

            oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        Wend
    End With
Next CurrRowShtSearchItem

CurrRowShtExtract = 0

'Mounting Height
For CurrRowShtSearchItem = 4 To 4
    Set oRange = oDoc.Range
    With oRange.Find
        .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1).Text
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        While .Execute = True
            oRange.MoveStart wdCharacter, 16
            oRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, 11

            CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1

            shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract + 1, 22) = oRange.Text

            oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        Wend
    End With
Next CurrRowShtSearchItem

CurrRowShtExtract = 0

'Clip Type
For CurrRowShtSearchItem = 6 To 6
    Set oRange = oDoc.Range
    With oRange.Find
        .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1).Text
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        While .Execute = True


            CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1

            shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract + 1, 19) = oRange.Text

            oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        Wend
    End With
Next CurrRowShtSearchItem

CurrRowShtExtract = 0

'Building
For CurrRowShtSearchItem = 7 To 7
    Set oRange = oDoc.Range
    With oRange.Find
        .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1).Text
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        While .Execute = True

            CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1

            shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract + 1, 9) = oRange.Text

            oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        Wend
    End With
Next CurrRowShtSearchItem

CurrRowShtExtract = 0

'Floor
For CurrRowShtSearchItem = 8 To 8
    Set oRange = oDoc.Range
    With oRange.Find
        .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1).Text
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        While .Execute = True

            CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1

            shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract + 1, 12) = oRange.Text

            oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        Wend
    End With
Next CurrRowShtSearchItem

CurrRowShtExtract = 0

'Room #
For CurrRowShtSearchItem = 9 To 9
    Set oRange = oDoc.Range
    With oRange.Find
        .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1).Text
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        While .Execute = True

            CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1

            shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract + 1, 13) = oRange.Text

            oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        Wend
    End With
Next CurrRowShtSearchItem

CurrRowShtExtract = 0

'Antenna
For CurrRowShtSearchItem = 10 To 10
    Set oRange = oDoc.Range
    With oRange.Find
        .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1).Text
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        While .Execute = True

            CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1

            shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract + 1, 21) = oRange.Text

            oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        Wend
    End With
Next CurrRowShtSearchItem

CurrRowShtExtract = 0

With oDoc.Content.Find
        .Text = "*Installation Instructions"
        .Replacement.Text = "Installation Instructions"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
oDoc.Save

'Installation
For CurrRowShtSearchItem = 5 To 5
    Set oRange = oDoc.Range
    With oRange.Find
        .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1).Text
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        While oRange.Find.Execute = True
            oRange.Select
            myPara = oDoc.Range(0, oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.End).Paragraphs.Count

            CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1

            shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract + 1, 14) = Left(oDoc.Paragraphs(myPara).Range, Len(oDoc.Paragraphs(myPara).Range) - 1)

            oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        Wend
    End With
Next CurrRowShtSearchItem

Cells.Replace What:="Installation Instructions:", Replacement:="", LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("U:U").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="m*", Replacement:="m", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

If WordNotOpen Then
    oWord.Quit
End If

If WordNotOpen Then
    oWord.Quit
End If

'Release object references

Set oWord = Nothing
Set oDoc = Nothing

Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
MsgBox "Word caused a problem. " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
If WordNotOpen Then
oWord.Quit
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions. This looks very plausible through that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your active worksheet has Model, Antenna, etc. in column A and the found details are to be output to column B:

```
Sub GetDocData()
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet, r As Long
Dim WordApp As New Word.Application, WordDoc As Word.Document
Set xlSheet = ActiveSheet
WordApp.Visible = True
With WordApp
  .Visible = False
  With .Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
    If .Show = -1 Then
      Set WordDoc = WordApp.ActiveDocument
    End If
  End With
  With WordDoc
    With .Range
      For r = 1 To xlSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        With .Find
          .ClearFormatting
          .Replacement.ClearFormatting
          .Replacement.Text = ""
          .Forward = True
          .Format = False
          .Wrap = wdFindContinue
          .Text = xlSheet.Range("A" & r) & ":"
          .Execute
        End With
        If .Find.Found = True Then
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            .End = .Paragraphs.First.Range.End - 1
            xlSheet.Range("B" & r).Value = .Text
        End If
      Next
    End With
  End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting code. I tried running it but nothing seems to happen. I may not have the excel sheet set up correctly per your assumption. 

Right now I have the output being placed into various columns based on how my excel spreadsheet is set up. Such as AP Name going into column A or AP Model going into column T. The search terms to look up are on another sheet and being referenced in the For loops before being found, copied, and then pasted into the corresponding columns.

Is there a way to simply modify the oRange.MoveEnd statements to make it just go to the end of the line?

Comment: I've been trying to modify it with something like this:

oRange.MoveEnd Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

But whenever I do I get "Error 4120: Bad Parameter"

Comment: Did you read the paragraph before the code in my answer? Nowhere did you give any indication that the Excel data are organised in anything other than the first column - even your '.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1)' implies as much. Obviously, if your workbook structure is different, you'll need to adapt the code accordingly. To work with columns instead of rows, only three lines in the code I posted would need editing. No additional code would be required.